# React, Fetch API and Filtering data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, fetch-api

I am unable to grab data from a URL I've fetched. I am trying to iterate over the fetched Array then count the amount of hours total in the objects. Here is an example array from my API. I am unable to count the total length of objects in the array with `this.state.users.length` until AFTER the render. And am therefore unable to grab hours from the array. What is the best way to handle this? My end goal is to add all the hours up in the array then render.

```
[
 {
   name: "a_example_010618",
   type: "A",
   key: 1,
   hours: 12
 },
 {
   name: "b_example2_010618",
   key: 2,
   type: "B",
   hours: 20
 },
 {
   name: "c_example_010618",
   key: 3,
   type: "C",
   hours: 8
 }
]
```

My fetch function:

```
loadFromApi() {
    fetch('/myAPI')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
         this.setState({ users: data })
     })
     .catch(error => console.log('error fetching', error))
}
```

**TRYING** to log out the hours into the console

```
  countData() {
    console.log('length: ' + this.state.users.length) // returning 0 
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.users.length; i++) {
      console.log('hours: ' + this.state.users[i].hours) // not running because the length is 0
    }
  }
```

Called on mount:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadFromApi()
    this.countData()
  }
```

Then stored in state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []
    }

    this.loadFromApi = this.loadFromApi.bind(this);
    this.countData = this.countData.bind(this);
  };
```

Render Example:

```
render() {
  console.log('render users: ' + this.state.users); // logs 0 then 3
  console.log('render hours: ' + this.state.users[0].hours); //throws err
  return(
    <div>
      hi
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the render function I am able to call `this.state.users.length` fine and log the value of 3, However I cannot display any other data from the API.

Comment: Where is your render function code ?

Comment: You need to call `countData` after the state is set. Not immediately after starting to fetch.

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI added example

Comment: @Bergi i tried calling `countData` in `componentDidUpdate` yet i still get the same problem. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling `countData` after setting `state`? Looks like this:

```
loadFromApi() {
    fetch('/myAPI')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ users: data })
            this.countData();
         })
        .catch(error => console.log('error fetching', error))
}
```

In `render()`:

```
render() {
  const { users } = this.state;
  console.log('render users: ' + users); // logs 0 then 3
  users && console.log('render hours: ' + users[0].hours); //conditioned rendering
  return(
    <div>
      hi
    </div>
  );

}
```

This line `users && console.log('render hours: ' + users[0].hours);`, simply says, if `users` is defined, log first users `hours`.